# Load Spinner content

Tags: android, android-spinner

Before marking as a duplicate please read the post.

I am using `Spinner` in my app and populate it with data from the server in `onCreate` method.
Everything works fine if during `onCreate` user is having internet connection.
In other case `Spinner` is having one item "Select an item"
I need a solution to load again the spinner's data at a run time
(if it hasn't been loaded during `onCreate()`) each time user clicks the spinner.
The ideal solution would be something like `onFocusChaneListenner` - here I could upload data from the server when user clicks on the spinner.
But unfortunately it seemes not to work and I can not see the choice.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

               // here would would be great to update when receive focus
            }
        });
```

I thought about implementation of a `custom Spinner`, which `onItemSelected` will be called when Spinner is having one or zero itebs.
But here user has to select something (or nothing) and then return to it again in order to see updated data so it seemes not ideal.
Should I just check whether data has been loaded after some period of time without relying on user's interraction with the Spinner?

Comment: you can use TimerTask untill your data not loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to load data on Spinner Interaction use `OnTouchListener`.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
          // load data here
       }
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I needed

Comment: Your Welcome :) @Androider